# Proper conversion of AWS Log Insights to Metrics for visualization and monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

### TL;DR;

What is the proper way to create a metric so that it generates reliable information about the log insights?

### What is desired

The current Log insights can be seen similar to the following

[image: AWS Log insights]

However, it becomes easier to analyse these logs using the metrics (mostly because you can have multiple sources of data in the same plot and even perform math operations between them).

### Solution according to docs

Allegedly, a log can be converted to a metric filter following a guide like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountingLogEventsExample.html). However, this approach does not seem to work entirely right (I guess because of the time frames that have to be imposed in the metric plots), providing incorrect information, for example:

[image: Dashboard]

### Issue with solution

In the previous image I've created a dashboard containing the metric count (the number 7), corresponding to the sum of events each 5 minutes. Also I've added a preview of the log insight corresponding to the information used to create the event.

However, as it can be seen, the number of logs is 4, but the event count displays 7. Changing the time frame in the metric generates other types of issues (e.g., selecting a very small time frame like 1 sec won't retrieve any data, or a slightly smaller time frame will now provide another wrong number: 3, when there are 4 logs, for example).

### P.S.

I've also tried converting the log insights to metrics using [this lambda function](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/#!/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:085576722239:applications%7Elogs-insights-to-metric) as suggested by [Danil Smirnov](https://blog.smirnov.la/cloudwatch-logs-insights-to-metrics-a2d197aac379) to no avail, as it seems to generate the same issues.